# How can I get current Zapier App version on zapier site

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

Is there any way user can check app version? Preferably via the UI on the zapier.com (not from the developer account)

It's needed for testing and reporting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If the integration is public on the Zapier site and the user is using the promoted version, then it's not possible for the end-user to see what version of the app they're using.

If they've been invited to a non-public version of the app, I believe it shows the version in the app title across the site (like `AppName (1.2.3)`).

Comment: Sure that's possible from the developer account. Originally I was asking if it's possible to do from the user (client) account who will use integration.

Answer (score 0):

*From Zapier community:*

Just to add some further clarity here, this is how we display versions:

- If the app has not been migrated and the version is deprecated, it
  will say so when the Zap is viewed in the editor.
- If the app has not been migrated and the version is NOT deprecated,
  you will see the version listed in the Zap in the Editor
- If the app has been migrated or you're on the latest version, you
  won't see the version listed and it won't say deprecated or anything
  else.

Hope that helps to clarify!